# Assigning a variable a random element from a finite set

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, how does one declare a variable to be a random element from a predefined finite set of values?  For example, suppose a user wants to assign the variable `fooBar` to be a random element from the set {1, 2, 3}.  How would one do this?

Answer (score 0):

From an object:

```
function pickRandomProperty(obj) {
    var result;
    var count = 0;
    for (var prop in obj)
        if (Math.random() < 1/++count)
           result = prop;
    return result;
}
```

From an array:

```
var rand = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
```